# PHP 8.0 Curl request is working but generates a Fatal Error in the logs

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I noticed in xampp error_log (Ubuntu 20 -> /opt/lampp/logs/error_log):

```
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/core/scrapers/ps3838/ps3838.rest.php on line 106
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/core/scrapers/ps3838/ps3838.rest.php:106
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/core/scrapers/ps3838/ps3838.rest.php(239): RestClient->request()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/core/scrapers/ps3838/ps.scraper.php(158): Ps3838->get_odds()
#2 {main}
```

The error is generated in a class I use to query an api.

```
if ($this->request_method === "POST") {
    $this->ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
} else {
    $this->ch = curl_init($url."?".$param);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
}
```

The weird part is that the code works as expected! no errors and I get the the response...
What is going on - why its logged as an error? how can it throw a Fatal error yet executing flawlessly?

Comment: There are two possibilities: this isn't the code that's throwing the error, or this isn't the code that's running successfully. Put some debugging statements in that part of the code and confirm which is the case.

Comment: @IMSoP its pointed in the error log (same error spammed all over the place) I run it, got the request result and this error is created on the log... Its 100% this code I never seen something like that if I add `some_fatal();` the execution fails so errors are working as expected.

Comment: Is the php_curl extension installed?

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes of course as I wrote its executing just fine - I don't understand why a Fatal error entry is generated in the log file....

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()` says, that the function is not available. That happens if the extension is missing.

Comment: Do you have any command-line scripts our cron jobs running? Perhaps it is one of those which is causing the error, because it is running with a different PHP configuration.

Comment: @IMSoP Holy... You are a genius I had a cron job running with another php version that doesn't have curl.